# Blender - 40 mins to export a 30 second fbx. Takes less than 1 second in Maya? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: export, keyframes, .fbx, rigify

I am working with mocap data.

The software I'm using exports a .blend file, of a skeleton rig, based on the rigify rig, with the mocap animation recorded onto lots of empties.

I want to bake keys onto the joints and export the animation as fbx, I am using the following process:

I select the metarig

Go to "pose" mode

Choose "animation > bake keys"
I turn on "visual keying" and press bake

This then bakes keys on every frame (takes about 5-10 mins)

Then,
I go "export fbx"
I turn on "selected objects"
Turn off "leaf bones"
Turn off "NLA strips" and "start/end keys"
Then I press "export"

The export process takes FOREVER.... like 30-40 mins to export a 30 second clip

I have a good computer/Ram/graphics card. In Maya, with the animation keys already baked onto a joints, exporting an fbx would take about 1 second.

What I am doing wrong?? Is there any way I can speed this up?

Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79859/blender-stops-responding-when-trying-to-export-fbx-with-empties-but-doesnt-with

Comment: FBX is Autodesk's format so it makes sense that Autodesk software should work well with it. Blender does not work well with FBX. If possible, I would recommend exploring other format options like Collada or Alembic. They should work better with Blender and still work with most other software.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest adding necessary animation strips into NLA editor, and disabling  all animation data except "NLA strips" from export. In this case, only necessary animation will be exported, instead of default `all objects` x `all animations`.